# Devise trying to save password attribute to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Running Rails 4.2 and devise 3.4.1

I've added "devise :database_authenticatable", to a User model, and everything works exactly as expected .... except, when the record is saved or created I get this error:

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'password' in 'field list': UPDATE `users` SET `password` = NULL, .....

The devise attribute/method 'password' is clearly being added to the sql but is not a column within the table.

I'm stumped ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your migration file if there is a encrypted_password field. Next check the structure of users table in database. There should be encrypted_password column too. You can also override devise views and see what happen inside form and try to debug it with console help.